# How to retrieve PID of a photo?

Tags: php, facebook, rest, facebook-fql

```
$pid = $fb->api(array( 
        'method' => 'fql.query', 
        'query' => 'SELECT first_name from user where uid='.$session['uid'])
    );



try { 
    $fb->api( array(
        'method' => 'photos.addTag', 
        'pid'   => $pid[0], 
        'tag_uid' => '100000492080016',
        'tag_text' => "hello",
        'x' => 65, 
        'y' => 65, 
    ) );
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    print_r($e);
}
```

When i use the above code in a facebook app, it shows the error

> Param pid must be a valid merged photo
>   id.

How can i resolve this problem? Or can you explain how to retrieve the PID of a pic in any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your query `SELECT first_name from user where uid='.$session['uid']` you are retriving only `first_name` from database, thats the problem i think.

so i think you need to change your query.

```
SELECT first_name,pid from user where uid='.$session['uid']
```

I am not as much familiar with Facebook APIs and all but might be i m true.

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you fro the reply. I figured out the way: select pid from photo where object_id=FBID